# Java, c#,kotlin

Tags: ассемблер, jvm

Позволяют ли эти языки производить побитовые и целочисленные операции с числами с плавающей точкой без преобразования типов, как на ассемблере и C? Чтобы было понятнее, беру в Си float n и добавляю к нему единицу сдвинутую на длину мантиссы в контексте целочисленной операции вследствие чего число float n вырастает в два раза (если конечно не происходит переполнение экспоненты). И как с этим в rust, go?

Comment: можно, но сложно - путем разбора на байтики. Это редкая операция, которая ненужна простым смертным.

Comment: Мне нужна эта операция, это открывает доступ к невероятным оптимизациям

Comment: Ниже человек ответил что в C# можно.

Comment: C# изначально проектировался как замена C++ для системного программирования (лол). Поэтому в нём предусмотрен unsafe режим и т. п. Kotlin и Go проектировались, имхо, для обратной цели: упростить прикладное программирование. Поэтому, возможно, в них нет подобного. А вот в Rust должно быть.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, спасибо за развернутый ответ. Ответы направляют меня в сторону "куда копать"

Comment: В java навскидку есть Float.floatToIntBits() и   Float.floatToRawIntBits(), чем отличаются не знаю, надо читать доки. Инфа не 100%, но скорей всего это оно. В rust можно в блоке unsafe{} привести указатель на флоат к указателю на инт.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В C# можно использовать явное расположение полей в структуре:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Data
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Int;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float Float;
}
```

Здесь оба поля расположены со смещением 0 от начала структуры. То есть они перекрываются. Это то же самое, что `union` в C/C++.

---

C# может работать с указателями, как C/C++. Использоваться они могут только в контексте `unsafe` и с включенной опцией компилятора.

```cs
unsafe
{
    float f = 0.5f;
    float* p = &f;
    int* n = (int*)p;
    // use (*n) somehow
}
```